# Optionally inherit from subclass of base class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

I have the following object structure: An `ItemCollection` class that stores items. A `GeneratorUnion` class that is a store of items and of `Generator`s to get items from where it populates the store when `getItems()` is called with `generate()`. Separately there is the `ItemZone` class which is a representation of putting the items physically in an area with some special handling of items when they are sent to other Zones - I'll skip details. The `ItemZone` should be able to inherit the `GeneratorUnion` with overriden `getItems()` or inherit from the `ItemsCollection` directly with normal `getItems()`

### How can do optional inheritance javascript and ES6 classes?

Is there a special constructor format that will take the required parent and inherit from it like:

```
class ItemZone{
   constructor(parentClass){
       if(parentClass instanceof ItemsCollection)
           this = new parentClass();
   }
}
```

I've drawn a rough class diagram below with the overridden methods in italic
[image: Items multiple Inheritance from CollectionItems Class]

Comment: Does not directly answers your question, but you should consider replacing your classes by factories, they would allow you to do that: `createItemZone = cond => cond ? createItemCollections() : createSomethingElse()`

Comment: I've never understood what factories are for, maybe now I see. Would the factory be a `ItemsCollectionFactory`? Or would it be an `ItemZone(collection)` factory which returns an overloaded version of the `collection`? How is this different to a decorator as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61912755/3343553?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such thing as optional inheritance.

This is just a case where inheritance is the wrong tool. Use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). You may even have your `ItemZone` implement the same interface as an `ItemsCollection` (if you really need this), basically implementing the [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) or [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) patterns.

Comment: Thank you for filling in my knowledge with the correct terminology, easy to search for it when you know the jargon! 
As I understand it, what has been demonstrated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913021/3343553 is the proxy pattern. 
For my specific context, using a Decorator would look like a `new Zone(collection)` returning a `ItemCollection` with some overridden `send()` and `empty()` and the additional properties.

Comment: @EdL Yes. And it shouldn't matter to your zone whether you pass a `GeneratorUnion`  collection or another type of collection.

Comment: I suppose that you can setup `new Zone(null)` to have some default behaviour of an empty `ItemsCollection` so it behaves like a normal class constructor too. Is this considered an antipattern?

Comment: @EdL I'd prefer to be explicit, but it should be fine. Ideally though the decorator only depends on the interface, without having a specific dependency on the "default".

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript a class inherits from another class via the extends keyword. What you really look for is to customize the grandchild class. You can achieve it like this

```
class Grandparent {
    getItems() {
        console.log(this.foo); //Proof that we have the object here
        console.log("grandparent");
    }

}

class Parent extends Grandparent {
    getItems() {
        console.log("parent");
    }
}

class Current extends Parent {
    getItems() {
        this.parentClass.prototype.getItems.call(this);
    }

    constructor(parentClass) {
        super();
        this.parentClass = parentClass;
        this.foo = "bar";
    }
}

var cr = new Current(Grandparent);
cr.getItems();
```

EDIT

To avoid setting all proxies as proxies one can do this for a predefined set:

```
class Grandparent {
    getItems() {
        console.log(this.foo); //Proof that we have the object here
        console.log("grandparent");
    }

}

class Parent extends Grandparent {
    getItems() {
        console.log("parent");
    }
}

class Current extends Parent {
    constructor(parentClass) {
        super();
        this.proxyFunctions = ["getItems"];
        this.parentClass = parentClass;
        for (let fn of this.proxyFunctions) this[fn] = this.parentClass.prototype[fn];
        this.foo = "bar";
    }
}

var cr = new Current(Grandparent);
cr.getItems();
```

Comment: I had considered this, now I understand it to be the Proxy pattern. I think since there is no need to control access to the underlying collection this is probably not the right solution as each time I add an ItemsCollection method I have to add a proxy function. Is there a way around having to make a new proxy function for each?

Comment: @EdL please take a look at the edit. You don't have to repeat the proxy definition, you can just specify what your proxies are and handle them with the simplicity of iteration.